# Getting double numbers from array_rand

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a Bingo script. I have already coded a 6x6 pattern with random numbers which have a certain range on each line. BUT now it outputs the same number multiple times, i want it to be all random numbers, can someone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Indzendopdracht 051R3</title>
</head>

<body>
<?PHP

function printBingocard(){

$bingoNumbers = array(
"rij_1" => array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),
"rij_2" => array(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29),
"rij_3" => array(30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39),
"rij_4" => array(40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49),
"rij_5" => array(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59),
"rij_6" => array(60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)
);



$rand_keys = array_rand($bingoNumbers, 1);  
$rows = array();


foreach($bingoNumbers["rij_1"] as $bn_rij1){
    if($bn_rij1 > 10 && $bn_rij1 <= 16){
      $rows["row1"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["rij_1"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["rij_1"])] ."</td>";
    }
}
foreach($bingoNumbers["rij_2"] as $bn_rij2){
    if($bn_rij2 > 20 && $bn_rij2 <= 26){
      $rows["row2"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["rij_2"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["rij_2"])] ."</td>";
    }
}
foreach($bingoNumbers["rij_3"] as $bn_rij3){
    if($bn_rij3 > 30 && $bn_rij3 <= 36){
      $rows["row3"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["rij_3"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["rij_3"])] ."</td>";
    }
}
foreach($bingoNumbers["rij_4"] as $bn_rij4){
    if($bn_rij4 > 40 && $bn_rij4 <= 46){
      $rows["row4"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["rij_4"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["rij_4"])] ."</td>";
    }
}
foreach($bingoNumbers["rij_5"] as $bn_rij5){
    if($bn_rij5 > 50 && $bn_rij5 <= 56){
      $rows["row5"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["rij_5"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["rij_5"])] ."</td>";
    }
}
foreach($bingoNumbers["rij_6"] as $bn_rij6){
    if($bn_rij6 > 60 && $bn_rij6 <= 66){
      $rows["row6"][]="<td>" . $bingoNumbers["rij_6"][array_rand($bingoNumbers["rij_6"])] ."</td>";
    }
}


echo "<table>";
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $r){
        echo $r;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}//END OF FUNCTION


printBingocard();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code should just print a random table from your array, but not with duplicate numbers ?

Comment: Yes, when it outputs for example 10 - 20 i dont want it to have duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)? As is right now, you're never checking for `array_rand()` producing a duplicate number, so yeah - you'll get dupes.

This is far more efficient:

```
foreach(array_keys($bingoNumbers) as $key) {
    shuffle($bingoNumbers[$key]);
}
```

One **SINGLE** loop, and each of those sub arrays is shuffled, without duplicates, in far far less code.

```js
$bingoNumbers = array(
 "rij_1" => array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),
 "rij_2" => array(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29),
 "rij_3" => array(30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39),
 "rij_4" => array(40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49),
 "rij_5" => array(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59),
 "rij_6" => array(60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)
);
 
foreach(array_keys($bingoNumbers) as $key)
 shuffle($bingoNumbers[$key]);
   
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($bingoNumbers as $v)
 echo "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $v) . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://viper-7.com/8z7zoQ)

If you only want a 6x6 grid, just [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) your sub arrays, e.g.

```js
$bingoNumbers = array(
 "rij_1" => array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),
 "rij_2" => array(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29),
 "rij_3" => array(30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39),
 "rij_4" => array(40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49),
 "rij_5" => array(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59),
 "rij_6" => array(60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)
);
 
foreach(array_keys($bingoNumbers) as $key)
 shuffle($bingoNumbers[$key]);
   
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($bingoNumbers as $v)
 echo "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array_slice($v, 0, 6)) . "</td></tr>";
                                             //^^^^^^^^^^^^ Just slice your sub array
echo "</table>";
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://viper-7.com/fNraoG)

Comment: So i have to replace all the foreach loops with the code you provided? I just did that but it gives me this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_shuffle() in C:\directory on line 28**

Comment: @Ixecube I think this was just a typo from Marc B, just change `array_shuffle()` to `shuffle()` and his code works perfectly fine

Comment: @Rizier123 It resolves the error, but now it shows nothing. Dont i have to use **["rij_1"]** in order to select the correct array?

Comment: @Ixecube Your function and your printing are also far too complicated, see: http://viper-7.com/xyPBGJ

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank you so much! It already solves a bunch. I just started PHP so it's still very new to me. Only thing left is to make it so that it has 6 columns instead of 10. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @Ixecube You mean that you have a 6x6 grid?

Comment: Whoops, yep, just `shuffle()`... fixed the answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes a 6x6 grid

Comment: @Ixecube Just slice your sub arrays from the 0's index to the 6't, e.g. http://viper-7.com/PwClEb

Comment: @MarcB If you think the edit was too huge, or disagree with, just edit or do a rollback :)

Comment: @Rizier123 i salute you. You just solved my issue which i was working on for about 2 weeks. Thank you so much :)